# Unable to configure log archive destination in oracle 11g express

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, database-backups

## I have **oracle 11g express** in machine & i want to change archive destination.

**Step 1** *Before Execute below script i have below screen output*

> SQL> `archive log list;`
>
> Database log mode              `Archive Mode`
>
> Automatic archival             `Enabled`
>
> Archive destination            `USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST`
>
> Oldest online log sequence     `1`
>
> Next log sequence to archive   `2`
>
> Current log sequence           `2`

**Step 2** *After execute script to change archive destination, i have below screen output*

> SQL> `ALTER SYSTEM SET log_archive_dest_1='LOCATION=c:\arch\arch\';`
>
> `System altered.`
>
> SQL> `archive log list;`
>
> Database log mode              `Archive Mode`
>
> Automatic archival             `Enabled`
>
> Archive destination            `c:\arch\arch\`
>
> Oldest online log sequence     `1`
>
> Next log sequence to archive   `2`
>
> Current log sequence           `2`

Now i have again shutdown and start my database instance then why my settings has been re change as previous stage as on first screen.

*Overall i'm not able to change archive destination.*

**Step 3** *Getting back below archive destination location*

> SQL> `shutdown immediate;`
>
> ORA-01109: `database not open`
>
> `Database dismounted.`
>
> `ORACLE instance shut down.`
>
> SQL> `startup mount;`
>
> `ORACLE instance started.`
>
> Total System Global Area `1068937216 bytes`
>
> Fixed Size                  `2260048 bytes`
>
> Variable Size             `616563632 bytes`
>
> Database Buffers          `444596224 bytes`
>
> Redo Buffers                `5517312 bytes`
>
> `Database mounted.`
>
> SQL> `archive log list;`
>
> Database log mode              `Archive Mode`
>
> Automatic archival             `Enabled`
>
> Archive destination            `USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST`
>
> Oldest online log sequence     `1`
>
> Next log sequence to archive   `2`
>
> Current log sequence           `2`

Comment: what do you mean by "-rechange as previous stage " , its clearly visible that  the archive destination is c:\arch\arch as you have set in alter system command , what is the problem now ?

Comment: after execute shutdown immediate and startup mount and recheck archive log list then getting back previous configuration `Like  archive log list;
**>"Archive destination  USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST"**

Comment: _Where i'm wrong or what i have missed?_.

Comment: you are not using spfile ,

use this

ALTER SYSTEM SET log_archive_dest_1='LOCATION=c:\arch\arch\' scope=spfile  ;    and restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spfile is missing in the command,

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET log_archive_dest_1='LOCATION=c:\arch\arch\' scope=spfile ; and restart
```